# hibernate @ManyToOne fails to insert properply, because FK id not yet created

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, relational-database, hibernate-annotations

In the class Order I have a property:

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;`

In the class OrderLine I have a property:

`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="OrderID")
private Order order;`

In the DB, orderline simply has a FK pointing to an order. And this is where the issue lies

I manually build an Order object, without an ID because it's set to auto generate, which I save using the appropriate DAO. The order table is filled correctly but the orderline table isn't.

The FK field of the order in orderline table is left blank. I assume it's because at the point of insert the order ID still has no ID.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

How do you persist your orderline instances?

You will have to set the instance of the order object in the orderline instance.

For example:

```
Order order = new Order();
// populate order



Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();

OrderLine orderline = new OrderLine();
orderline.setOrder(order); // set the order instance
// populate orderline

orderLines.add(orderline);

order.setOrderLines(orderLines);

order.persist();
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I forgot to refer the orderline to the order ie: orderline.setOrder(order);